# how to send current location to specific people in firebase database

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

i want to send current location to specific people in my firebase database when a button is clicked. These people change from device to device depending on which people the user has selected to get notification about the sender's location. I have a clue on what's required of me to do but i can't seem to figure it out.

This is the class i used to read the user's current location:
and in my menuActivity i want to call the latitude and the longitude when sendLoc button is clicked

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OnMapReadyCallback {


ImageButton fakeCallBtn;
Button sendLoc;
ImageButton notif;
ImageButton flash;
private GoogleMap mMap;
LocationManager locationManager;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference mUserRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("RescueX ");

    sendLoc=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Locationbtn);
     sendLoc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Location l = gt.getLocation();
            if( l == null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"GPS unable to get 
    Value",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                double lat = l.getLatitude();
                double lon = l.getLongitude();
                Intent lociIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, 
         ViewLocation.class);
                lociIntent.putExtra("lat", lat);
                lociIntent.putExtra("lon",lon);
                startActivity(lociIntent);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," Emergency Alert has 
      been Successfully sent ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {


        mUserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;

    }


    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                //get latitude
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                //get longitude
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                    String str = addressList.get(0).getCountryName() + ",";
                    str += addressList.get(0).getLocality();
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(str));  // this is the location i want to share with the specific people in my database
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10.2f));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }


            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if(currentUser == null){

        sendToStart();

    } else {

        mUserRef.child("online").setValue("true");

    }

}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if(currentUser != null) {

        mUserRef.child("online").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

    }

}

private void sendToStart() {

    Intent startIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, Home.class);
    startActivity(startIntent);
    finish();

}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    if(item.getItemId()== R.id.log_out){
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        sendToStart();

    }



    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent notifIntent= new Intent(MenuActivity.this, Settings.class);
        startActivity(notifIntent);
    }
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.all_users){

        Intent usersIntent= new Intent(MenuActivity.this, UsersActivity.class);
        startActivity(usersIntent);

    }

    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_profile_layout) {
        Intent searchIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, Profile.class);
        startActivity(searchIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_users_activity) {
        Intent searchIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, UsersActivity.class);
        startActivity(searchIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_history_layout) {
        Intent searchIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, History.class);
        startActivity(searchIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_help_layout) {
        Intent searchIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, Help.class);
        startActivity(searchIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_feedback_layout) {
        Intent searchIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, Feedback.class);
        startActivity(searchIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_signout_layout) {
        Intent searchIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, SignOut.class);
        startActivity(searchIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_friends_layout) {
        Intent searchIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, FriendsActivity.class);
        startActivity(searchIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        Intent searchIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, Share.class);
        startActivity(searchIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
    }


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}}
```

this is the class that creates a group that should be sent the location when a button is clicked to send the location:

```
public class EmergencyList extends AppCompatActivity {
private Toolbar mToolbar;

private TextView mProfileName, mProfileStatus, mProfileFriendsCount;
private Button mProfileSendReqBtn, mDeclineBtn;

private DatabaseReference mUsersDatabase;

private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

private DatabaseReference mFriendReqDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mFriendDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mNotificationDatabase;
private ImageView mProfileImage;


private DatabaseReference mRootRef;

private FirebaseUser mCurrent_user;

private String mCurrent_state;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_emergency_list);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.user_Appbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Who to notify in emergency");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    final String user_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_id");


    mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user_id);
    mFriendReqDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Connection_req");
    mFriendDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Emergency_Contacts");
    mNotificationDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Emergency_Notification");
    mCurrent_user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();




    mProfileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
    mProfileName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_displayName);
    mProfileStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_status);
    mProfileFriendsCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_totalFriends);
    mProfileSendReqBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.profile_send_req_btn);
    mDeclineBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.profile_decline_btn);


    mCurrent_state = "not_emergency_contact";

    mDeclineBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mDeclineBtn.setEnabled(false);


    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading User Data");
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while we load the user data.");
    mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    mProgressDialog.show();



    mUsersDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String display_name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
            String status = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
            String image = dataSnapshot.child("profile_picture").getValue().toString();

            mProfileName.setText(display_name);
            mProfileStatus.setText(status);

            Picasso.with(EmergencyList.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.my_profile).into(mProfileImage);

            if(mCurrent_user.getUid().equals(user_id)){

                mDeclineBtn.setEnabled(false);
                mDeclineBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                mProfileSendReqBtn.setEnabled(false);
                mProfileSendReqBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }


            //--------------- FRIENDS LIST / REQUEST FEATURE -----

            mFriendReqDatabase.child(mCurrent_user.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(user_id)){

                        String req_type = dataSnapshot.child(user_id).child("emergency_type").getValue().toString();

                        if(req_type.equals("received")){

                            mCurrent_state = "emergency_received";
                            mProfileSendReqBtn.setText("Accept As Emergency ");

                            mDeclineBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            mDeclineBtn.setEnabled(true);


                        } else if(req_type.equals("sent")) {

                            mCurrent_state = "emergency_sent";
                            mProfileSendReqBtn.setText("Cancel Emergency Request");

                            mDeclineBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            mDeclineBtn.setEnabled(false);

                        }

                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();


                    } else {


                        mFriendDatabase.child(mCurrent_user.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(user_id)){

                                    mCurrent_state = "emergency_contact";
                                    mProfileSendReqBtn.setText("Remove "+mProfileName.getText() + " As Emergency Contact");

                                    mDeclineBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    mDeclineBtn.setEnabled(false);

                                }

                                mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                            }
                        });

                    }



                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    mProfileSendReqBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            mProfileSendReqBtn.setEnabled(false);

            // --------------- NOT FRIENDS STATE ------------

            if(mCurrent_state.equals("not_emergency_contact")){


                DatabaseReference newNotificationref = mRootRef.child("Emergency_Notification").child(user_id).push();
                String newNotificationId = newNotificationref.getKey();

                HashMap<String, String> notificationData = new HashMap<>();
                notificationData.put("from", mCurrent_user.getUid());
                notificationData.put("type", "request");

                Map requestMap = new HashMap();
                requestMap.put("Connection_req/" + mCurrent_user.getUid() + "/" + user_id + "/emergency_type", "sent");
                requestMap.put("Connection_req/" + user_id + "/" + mCurrent_user.getUid() + "/emergency_type", "received");
                requestMap.put("Emergency_Notifications/" + user_id + "/" + newNotificationId, notificationData);

                mRootRef.updateChildren(requestMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                        if(databaseError != null){

                            Toast.makeText(EmergencyList.this, "There was some error in sending request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {

                            mCurrent_state = "emergency_sent";
                            mProfileSendReqBtn.setText("Cancel Emergency Contact");

                        }

                        mProfileSendReqBtn.setEnabled(true);


                    }
                });

            }


            // - -------------- CANCEL REQUEST STATE ------------

            if(mCurrent_state.equals("emergency_sent")){

                mFriendReqDatabase.child(mCurrent_user.getUid()).child(user_id).removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                        mFriendReqDatabase.child(user_id).child(mCurrent_user.getUid()).removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {


                                mProfileSendReqBtn.setEnabled(true);
                                mCurrent_state = "not_emergency_contact";
                                mProfileSendReqBtn.setText("Add As Emergency Contact");

                                mDeclineBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                mDeclineBtn.setEnabled(false);


                            }
                        });

                    }
                });

            }


            // ------------ REQ RECEIVED STATE ----------

            if(mCurrent_state.equals("emergency_received")){

                final String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

                Map friendsMap = new HashMap();
                friendsMap.put("Emergency_Contact/" + mCurrent_user.getUid() + "/" + user_id + "/date", currentDate);
                friendsMap.put("Emergency_Contact/" + user_id + "/"  + mCurrent_user.getUid() + "/date", currentDate);


                friendsMap.put("Connection_req/" + mCurrent_user.getUid() + "/" + user_id, null);
                friendsMap.put("Connection_req/" + user_id + "/" + mCurrent_user.getUid(), null);


                mRootRef.updateChildren(friendsMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {


                        if(databaseError == null){

                            mProfileSendReqBtn.setEnabled(true);
                            mCurrent_state = "emergency_contact";
                            mProfileSendReqBtn.setText("Remove " + mProfileName.getText() + " As Emergency Contact");

                            mDeclineBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            mDeclineBtn.setEnabled(false);

                        } else {

                            String error = databaseError.getMessage();

                            Toast.makeText(EmergencyList.this, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }

                    }
                });

            }


            // ------------ UNFRIENDS ---------

            if(mCurrent_state.equals("emergency_contact")){

                Map unfriendMap = new HashMap();
                unfriendMap.put("Emergency_Contact/" + mCurrent_user.getUid() + "/" + user_id, null);
                unfriendMap.put("Emergency_Contact/" + user_id + "/" + mCurrent_user.getUid(), null);

                mRootRef.updateChildren(unfriendMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {


                        if(databaseError == null){

                            mCurrent_state = "not_emergency_contact";
                            mProfileSendReqBtn.setText("Add As Emergency Contact");

                            mDeclineBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            mDeclineBtn.setEnabled(false);

                        } else {

                            String error = databaseError.getMessage();

                            Toast.makeText(EmergencyList.this, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }

                        mProfileSendReqBtn.setEnabled(true);

                    }
                });

            }


        }
    });


}


}
```

this is the class where i call the people from my Emergency_Contacts in my database:

```
public class EmergencyFragment extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView mFriendsList;

private DatabaseReference mFriendsDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mUsersDatabase;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

private String mCurrent_user_id;

private View mMainView;


public EmergencyFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_emergency, container, false);

    mFriendsList = (RecyclerView) mMainView.findViewById(R.id.emergency_contacts);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mCurrent_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    mFriendsDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Emergency_Contact").child(mCurrent_user_id);
    mFriendsDatabase.keepSynced(true);
    mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    mUsersDatabase.keepSynced(true);


    mFriendsList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mFriendsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return mMainView;
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Emergency, EmergencyFragment.EmergencyViewHolder> emergencyRecyclerViewAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Emergency, EmergencyFragment.EmergencyViewHolder>(

            Emergency.class,
            R.layout.users_emergency_layout,
            EmergencyFragment.EmergencyViewHolder.class,
            mFriendsDatabase


    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final EmergencyFragment.EmergencyViewHolder emergencyViewHolder, Emergency emergency, int i) {

            emergencyViewHolder.setDate(emergency.getDate());

            final String user_id = getRef(i).getKey();

            mUsersDatabase.child(user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    final String Username = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    String userThumb = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();



                    emergencyViewHolder.setName(Username);
                    emergencyViewHolder.setUserImage(userThumb, getContext());

                    emergencyViewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]{" Open Details", "view history"};

                            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

                            builder.setTitle("Select Options");
                            builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                                    //Click Event for each item.
                                    if(i == 0){

                                        Intent emergencyIntent = new Intent(getContext(), EmergencyList.class);
                                        emergencyIntent.putExtra("user_id", user_id);
                                        startActivity(emergencyIntent);

                                    }
   if(i == 1){

                                        Intent historyIntent = new Intent(getContext(), History.class);
                                        historyIntent.putExtra("user_id", user_id);
                                        historyIntent.putExtra("Username", Username);
                                        startActivity(historyIntent);

                                    }


                                }
                            });

                            builder.show();

                        }
                    });


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
    };

    mFriendsList.setAdapter(emergencyRecyclerViewAdapter);


}


public static class EmergencyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;

    public EmergencyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;

    }

    public void setDate(String date){

        TextView userStatusView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.contacts_status);
        userStatusView.setText(date);

    }

    public void setName(String name){

        TextView userNameView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.contacts_name);
        userNameView.setText(name);

    }

    public void setUserImage(String thumb_image, Context ctx){

        CircleImageView userImageView = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.image_display);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(thumb_image).placeholder(R.drawable.my_profile).into(userImageView);

    }



    }


}
```

}

i want the location to be stored or opened on the history class now i am not sure how to get the location from the menuactivity class -> Emergency_Contacts then to -> history where it's going to be displayed.

Comment: AL. do you have an idea on how i need to solve this?